# Is it the true way to implement spring security & CXF webservice

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-security, cxf

i create a webservice as below:

web.xml

```
<display-name>MyService</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

beans.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />

<jaxrs:server id="employeeService" address="/employeeservices">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="empService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="empService" class="com.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.dao.EmployeeDao"/>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" >
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"></http-basic>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="userAuthorService" class="com.auth.UserAuthorService"/>
<beans:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.auth.UserBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="Name Of Your Realm"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthorService">
         <password-encoder ref="bcryptPasswordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="bcryptPasswordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="5" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>
```

1. By this configuration, is it flow of request process? :
   request -> Spring security(check authentication) -> cxf -> response.
2. Are there any issues in this configuration when I deploy it in the real sever? what is the standard configuration when using cxf and spring ?
3. when i call right uri:http://localhost:8089/MyService/rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetals?employeeId=004. its ok.
   But call wrong uri: http://localhost:8089/MyService/rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetallll?employeeId=004. It throw exception:

> WARNING: No operation matching request path "/MyService/rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetallll" is found, Relative Path: /getemployeedetal, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
>   Jun 07, 2016 1:55:17 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
>
> WARNING: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:110)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:149)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:477)

So how can i filter the right uri before access controller class.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By this configuration, is it flow of request process? : request ->
>   Spring security(check authentication) -> cxf -> response.

Yes, because J2EE filters are executed around J2EE servlets (before and after euqeust), so springSecurityFilterChain will be executed before CXFServlet

> Are there any issues in this configuration when I deploy it in the
>   real sever?

This is not necessary with latests versions of CXF

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

Also you are catching in CXFServlet `/rest/*` but in auth `*`. Is this an issue? Do you need rest services without authentication? Is difficult to analyze issues if we do not know the context of your system. Detail your doubts and I could try to help

> what is the standard configuration when using cxf and spring ?

There is no any recommended configuration, because CXF can be used with spring or standalone, jax-ws or jax-rs, as a server or acting as a client, with authentication executed via spring security or integrated with RequestContextFilter or inInterceptor in jax-rs server or even at global level in CXF bus.

If you are talking about the necessary modules to configure so CXF was executed with spring, you have the needed ones.

For authentication, you could consider use a JWT token instead of a bcrypt passwod.

> when i call right
>   uri:http://localhost:8089/MyService/rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetals?employeeId=004.
>   its ok. But call wrong uri:
>   http://localhost:8089/MyService/rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetallll?employeeId=004.
>   It throw exception:
>   WARNING: No operation matching request path

This warning is normal. The server is responding with an http error code  **404-Not found** because there is no resource available at `rest/employeeservices/getemployeedetallll`

> So how can i filter the right uri before access controller class.

CXF is doing for you by returning a 404 if the path is not found. It is the correct behaviour. Do you mean  CXF uri filter be executed before spring-security? You can not with this configuration because auth filter is previous.